# Will Delphi XE5 work under Windows 10?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe5

I want to install my Windows 10 upgrade.  But before I do, can anyone tell me if I can expect any problems with Delphi XE5 running under Windows 10?

Has anyone running Delphi XE5 installed Windows 10?  If so, were there any unexpected consequences?

Comment: @warren this comment looks odd now that the earlier ones are deleted, delete perhaps?

Comment: For future readers; I have used Delphi XE through XE8, and Delphi 10, on Windows 10, with no problems.  There were problems with Delphi 2007's debugger, starting with Windows 7, fixed with a patch, but I am unaware of any later versions of Delphi having any problem with any version of Windows.

Comment: Just confirming that Delphi XE2 works fine in Win10 (when installing run as admin).

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone running Delphi XE5 installed Windows 10? If so, were there any unexpected consequences?

Delphi XE5 installs and works perfectly well on Windows 10.

In fact, you can run pretty much any old version of Delphi on Windows 10. I've installed Delphi 6 on Windows 10. For the older versions that pre-date Vista you typically need to ensure that the program's installation directory is modifiable because those older versions do make modifications to their installation directory. But all that was cleared up long before XE5 so you'll have no issues with XE5 on Windows 10.